# How do i use mongoose's $lookup to query from multiple collections and arrive at a unique distinct set of results

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have 3 collections and a simplified representation of their schema

1. Batches

- units
- sku

2. Products

- description
- sku

3. Sales

- quantityShipped
- sku

I am trying to get a list of unique products with their description and stock (units - quantityShipped).

I tried this

```
db.products.aggregate([
{ $match: {} },
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "sales",
    localField: "sku",
    foreignField: "sku",
    as: "sales",
  },
},
{ $unwind: "$sales" },
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "batches",
    localField: "sku",
    foreignField: "sku",
    as: "batches",
  },
},
{ $unwind: "$batches" },
{
  $project: {
    sku: 1,
    productId: "$products._id",
    productDescription: "$products.description",
    description: 1,
    unitsLeft: {
      $subtract: ["$batches.units", "$sales.quantityShipped"],
    },
  },
},
{
  $group: {
     _id: {
       sku: "$_id",
       productId: "$_id",
       description: "$description",
     },
    _id: "$_id",
    total: {
      $sum: "$unitsLeft",
    },
  },
},
```

]);

What am I missing?

Example Inputs:

```
- Product

{  
   description: "A black Shoe",
   sku: "HT124"
}

- Batch

{ units: 130, sku:"HT124" }

- Sales 

{ quantityShipped: 100, sku: "HT124"}

    - SAMPLE OUTPUT

[ { _id: "productId1", description: "product description1", stock: 30}, { _id: "productId2", description: "product description2", stock: 40}]
```

Comment: Can you an input and output example?

Comment: Thank you @J.F. I have updated the question with sample inputs and outputs

Answer (score 0):

Here are the observations which seems like error/mistakes I spotted when importing your code and running it in Mongo playground:

1. the case of collection name: some of them are capital letter and some of them are small letter. This can cause empty `$lookup` and thus missed-out documents in `$unwind`
2. You should `$group` the sales quantity to get the total sold quantity before performing `$subtract` to get remaining stocks; In your current code, you will get incorrect calculation result by duplicating existing stock count

Here is a [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cJqQvumOmce) that "corrected" above points for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ray and for sharing the mongo playground very useful. point 1 raised is just a typo on my end. Though I am still reading documentation to get to know the use of $first, I added another batch for the SKU "HT124" and the stock count decreased and became negative. Technically it should increase. What could be wrong?

Comment: update your sample input & expected output as suggested by @JF